# Cast Linq query to class that inherit a dictionary

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a class which inherit a dictionary.

```
class SymbolsWithQuotes: Dictionary<string, IList<Quotes>> // ex: key: AAPL value: quotations for the last year
{
       // Empty class

}
```

At first, I think its a good idea to inherit a dictionary for readability but now I have a Linq query where I end the statement by:

```
ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value.ArrayObjects() 
                                     .Select(blabla));
```

And I have no idea how to cast it to my class SymbolsWithQuotes.

So three questions:

1 / Was is it a good idea to inherit a dictionary for readability ?

2 / Is there a solution to cast my linq query to my object SymbolsWithQuotes

3 / Do you see an alternative solution easier to read and to maintain ? Or should I just use Dictionary> everywhere instead of object SymbolsWithQuotes

Thanks

[Edit] I precise that my linq Query does returns a type

```
Dictionary<string, IList<Quotes>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `SymbolsWithQuotes` is nothing but an empty class, then I suggest you not use it. As you've seen, it makes things a bit difficult.

If you just want to create an alias for the name, you could use the [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
using SymbolsWithQuotes = Dictionary<string, IList<Quotes>>;
```